# Why does imagepickercontroller:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo get called when app wakes up after going to background during compressing screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

During video picking of [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html). The control chooses the video and goes to compress screen. At this point the app goes to background. When the app wakes up the compress is dismissed and the [imagepickercontroller:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController%3adidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo%3a) delegate method is called. Even before compression is complete.

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there a way to resume the compression?
3. Are there any compression handlers for the UIImagePickerController?

Sample Code used [PhotoPicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196)

Comment: post code what u tried ?

Comment: I am using the apple sample app PhotoPicker [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196)

Comment: This is same as my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385175/uiimagepickercontroller-calls-didfinishpickingmediawithinfo-if-i-send-app-to-bac
@Rushabh you can see code at above link